# Meteor repeated task scheduler once at the start of the month

Tags: meteor

A Meteor server code needs to run on the first second of every months "billing system". What would be a light weigh efficient way to go about it?
1)vsivsi:job-collection
2)percolate:synced-cron
Seam to be over kill. Any suggestion? thx

Comment: we're using synced-cron, as you've mentioned. what you describe is a job for cron, so i don't see a cron solution as being overkill.

Comment: @zim I added percolate:synced-cron to the Meteor project, are you able to give the solution using this package? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using percolate:synced-cron, then somewhere on the server, you would run code that looks like this.

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
    SyncedCron.add({
        name: 'Do Billing Task',
        schedule: function(parser) {
            return parser.text('on the first day of the month');
        },
        job: function() {
            DoBillingTask();
        }
    });

    SyncedCron.start();
});
```

cron itself is lightweight and is suited to the task you describe.

for the text, "on the first day of the month", i picked something that sounds like it would fit your needs. but that parser package has a lot of flexibility, you can read about it here:

http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#cron